# Why my image is not displaying in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to show an imagen taken with the camera and it's saved in file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/myapp.example/cache/1569223935056.jpg

```
 getImage() {
    this.data = localStorage.getItem("photoTakenPath")
    var filename = this.data.substring(this.data.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    var path = this.data.substring(0, this.data.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    this.file.readAsDataURL(path, filename).then(res => {
      this.cop = res;
    });
    console.log(this.cop)
  }
```

And in my HTML

```
<ion-thumbnail slot="start">
    <img [src]="cop" alt="Image" />
  </ion-thumbnail>
```

But when I saw this:
[what is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COcry.png)

Comment: Looks like the width and height is being set to 0

Comment: I set those values but it still showing nothing

Comment: Check if you are passing the correct data to the [src]. Also test it with the base64 in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html